# Uniqueness of neural networks

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network

I want to ask about the key-features of neural networks for **Machine Learning**.

1. what are types of problems that *can't* be solved by any machine
   learning algorithm *but* neural networks?
2. what are types of problems that *can* be solved by a variety of machine learning algorithms but are *best* solved using neural networks? and in contrast, what are types of problems that are *worst* solved using neural networks?

Comment: If this is homework, it should be labelled as such.

Comment: @DonReba
 Actually, this is not a homework, but I'm doing a tiny research to prove to my classmates that neural networks hasn't become extinct! it's all about that they have stable implementation (note.. I'm not saying they are stable, the implementations are).

Answer (score 1):

You may probably want to check [Problems Commonly Solved With Neural Networks](http://www.heatonresearch.com/online/introduction-neural-networks-java-edition-2/chapter-1/page3.html)

> The following four types of problem are frequently solved with neural
>   networks:
>
> - Classification
> - Prediction
> - Pattern recognition
> - Optimization

There may be some scenarios where machine learning is not useful. To point out one here is a **[tutorial](http://cdixon.org/2009/08/20/machine-learning-is-really-good-at-partially-solving-just-about-any-problem/)** listing one of them.

> The Netflix Challenge is a case in point: hundreds of the best
>   researchers in the world worked on the problem for 2 years and the
>   (apparent) winning team got a 10% improvement over Netflix’s in-house
>   algorithm.  This is consistent with my own experience, having spent
>   many years and dollars on machine learning projects.